# Why is parent div not the same height as a child?

Tags: html, css

I have a link that looks like a button and I would like to set the background colour to be different.

However, I don't understand why my `holder` div does not take the same height as it's child. I doesn't take into consideration padding.

Is there a clean way to fix this?

```css
.link {
  background-color: green;
  padding: .9rem 3rem;
}

.holder {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <a href="#" class="link">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block` to your `.link` element:

```css
.link {
  background-color: green;
  padding: .9rem 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.holder {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <a href="#" class="link">LINK</a>
</div>
```

By default, `<a>` elements are `display: inline`, and do not have their layout impacted by **[the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block)**. That is to say, they do not allow for a `height` or `width` to be set, and do not respect vertical padding and margins.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag default `display` is `inline`, so its parent will [display it vertically along its line box](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) (based on the `vertical-align` property), you need to change it to `display: block` or `inline-block`, depending on what you’re looking for;

```css
.link {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  padding: .9rem 3rem;
}

.holder {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <a href="#" class="link">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because by default `a` tag will have the property of `display: inline;` so make sure to change the `anchor` tag to `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`